# When in Editor Template, how can I put javascript in the head section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I hava an editor template for, let's say, date:

```
@model DateTime
@section AdditionalJavaScript2
{
   /* some js code */
}

@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("d.M.yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

Now, I would like to put some js code into the HEAD section, but this doesn't work.

Of course, I have a this section in my layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
  ...
  @RenderSection("AdditionalJavaScript2", required: false)
</head>
```

It works from the plain view, but not from partial view (editor template).

Why?

And, is there a workaround?

Thanks,

Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial-view does not use a template, it returns "raw" html to be included in your page (by Javascript). It does not have access to anything but the stream it returns itself.

Think of it like this: You typically call a partial view from Javascript/AJAX to get some new html. You get the return, and replace some DIV-tag. How can the system (FireFox, Chrome, ...) know, that there is some extra section of data that needs to replace something in the HEAD tag.

There are some workarounds:

- Don't put the script in the HEAD
- Add a parameter switch betweed the html and the script. You need to client-side calls, one to get the html, and one for the script. You include the calls to the partial-view on two locations on your page.
- Separate the script and the html using some pre-defined tag like `<!-- SEPERATOR -->`, and let the calling code split the result, and put it in the correct position.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll have to mix the js in the html.
I'm trying to make a AutoComplete editor template, so it is not called from the client (ajax) but as a part of the page generation process.
Don't know how to "post-process" the whole page and move the separator-tagged content to HEAD :(